# Can meta-regression for multilevel data structures be used to evaluate resistance training programs?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, meta-regression

Consider this meta study: [Strength and hypertrophy adaptions
between low vs high-load resistance training](https://elementssystem.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Schoenfeld-17-altas-bajas.pdf). The authors use "robust variance meta-regression for multilevel data structures" to summarize info from 21 studies on strength training with respect to which rep range is optimal for strength and muscle size (hypertrophy).

The details of their methodology is beyond me. However I have some experience in signal processing and statistics. I know that if I have several noisy measurements of the same signal I can average. The noise is random and will cancel out, the signal is not. I also imagine that if I have two studies that measure two different variables that are highly correlated there may exist some statistical method to use the results from both studies to both improve the measurements and to estimate the correlation.
However the variables must be closely related. As an example say that study A says that 15 reps are better than 10 reps for hypertrophy (muscle growth) in the leg press for young men. However study B says that 5 reps are better than 12 reps for hypertrophy in the bench press for women over 40. What are we to conclude from this? The variables are in this case to disparate and I doubt that any statistical wizardry can extract more info from this.

Within the strength training and bodybuilding communities it is well known from practical experience that efficacy with respect to strength decreases monotonically with number of repetitions. Train heavy or go home!
Hypertrophy however increases increases from 1 to 10 and then decreases from 10 and out (the optimal number is believed to be around 10 but also depend on muscle fiber composition). Strength and hypertrophy are correlated. However strength seem to be the product of muscle size and neural efficiency. The correlation is therefore not 1 to 1.

Unfortunately the 21 studies involved do not test say high load = 5 repetitions vs low load = 10 repetitions. High load ranges from 3 to 12 and low load from 16 to a whopping 150!
Within the strength and bodybuilding communities this would be considered ridiculous since anything over 20 repetitions is aerobics ;-).

The meta-study seem to lump all rep ranges into either high load or low load. However with such wildly varying rep ranges many of the values are bound to be misclassified. 12 is not really a high load.
If the efficacy of reps with respect to hypertrophy was a monotonous decreasing or increasing function this would maybe not be a problem.

I have also found two papers that critize this paper and that claims that this statistical methodology is not applicable to resistance training because of the disparate conditions:

[Reliability of meta-analyses to evaluate resistance
training programmes](http://antonioarruda.com.br/artigos/artigo05.pdf).

[Is There Any Practical Application of Meta-Analytical Results in Strength Training?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312040358_Is_There_Any_Practical_Application_of_Meta-Analytical_Results_in_Strength_Training)